# SQL To sum up amount for multiple rows at same column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to sum up the amount for different products but same month for same serviceid.  Here is the table:

```
ServiceID   PRODUCT AMT DATE
1           prod1   20  1/1/2013
1           prod2   40  1/1/2013
1           prod1   30  2/1/2013
1           prod2   50  2/1/2013
```

I need to add prod1+prod2 for 1/1/2013, prod1+prod2 for 2/1/2013
This is the result that I want:

```
ServiceID   PRODUCT AMT DATE
1           prod1   60  1/1/2013
1           prod2   80  2/1/2013

select serviceID, product, sum(amt), date
from table
where date >= 1/1/2013
and date <= 2/1/2013
group by 1, 2, 4
```

The group by doesn't get the result that I want.

In reality I can't specify product because it has more than what I post here.

Comment: Why is `prod1` and not `prod2` in the aggregated result for  `prod1+prod2` for `1/1/2013` = 60 ?

Comment: My bad! the result is:ServiceID PRODUCT AMT DATE
1 prod1&prod2 60 1/1/2013
1 prod1&prod2 80 2/1/2013

Comment: Are you sure about the date format? Might be different for query and the way it stored in the DB. Try to type-cast it to verify, e.g. CAST('20130101' AS datetime). Double-check mm and dd are converted properly (i.e. try date as '20131231' too)

Comment: Yes I know how to use cast. I just tried to make question simple.

Answer (score 0):

you can use DATEADD, DATEDIFF to get monthly aggregation

```
SELECT serviceID, 
       STUFF( ( SELECT DISTINCT '&' + PRODUCT 
                FROM Table1 T1
                WHERE T1.ServiceID = T.ServiceID
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)') , 1,1,'') as Products,
       sum(amt) as totalAmount,
       DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,[DATE]), 0) as month
FROM Table1 T
GROUP BY serviceId, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,[DATE]), 0)
```

As latest comment, adding total column using cross apply

```
SELECT T1.ServiceID, PRODUCT, AMT, [DATE], C.Total
FROM Table1 T1
CROSS APPLY
(
SELECT serviceID, 
       sum(amt) as Total,
       DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,[DATE]), 0) as month
FROM Table1 T
GROUP BY serviceId, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,[DATE]), 0)
) C
where T1.ServiceID = C.serviceId
      AND T1.[DATE] = C.month
```

Comment: I just tried.  It only added the months but not the amount of prod1+prod2 for each month

Comment: @angelcake, need to remove product in that case, try now

Comment: Yes that works only if group by DATEADD, but I need to include other columns.  How do I do that?

Comment: you mean , you want the product column as prod1,prod2 ( a comma seperated list) ?

Comment: I want to show the result like this.                                 SERVICEID PRODUCT      SUM(AMT) DATE                                 1         prod1&prod2  60       1/1/2013                           1         prod1&prod2  80       2/1/2013

Comment: Hi RADAR, yes it works, sorry for the delay cause I came out another format that I want to use and I was trying but haven't been successful yet.                                           ServiceID   PRODUCT AMT DATE  TOTAL
1           prod1   20  1/1/2013  1           prod2   40  1/1/2013        60
1           prod1   30  2/1/2013    
1           prod2   50  2/1/2013 80

Comment: Hi RADAR, yes it works, sorry for the delay cause I came out another format that I want to use and I was trying but haven't been successful yet. I try to put total in a new column on the right (sorry I can't line them up well in the post):               ServiceID PRODUCT AMT DATE     TOTAL
1        prod1   20  1/1/2013    
1        prod2   40  1/1/2013  60
1        prod1   30  2/1/2013    
1        prod2   50  2/1/2013 80

Answer (score 0):

```
select serviceID, 'prod1+prod2', sum(amt), date
from table
where date >= 1/1/2013
and date <= 2/1/2013
group by 1, 4
```